# Can't Override getValue() method of Vaadin ComboBox

Tags: java, overriding

```
  @Override
    public <E extends Enum<E>> E getValue(){
        return (E) super.getValue();
    }
```

Why is this overriding not working?
The error that Idea is returning is that both methods have the same erasure but they are not overriding each other.

**Edit:**

Cannot Overload a Method Where the Formal Parameter Types of Each Overload Erase to the Same Raw Type

A class cannot have two overloaded methods that will have the same signature after type erasure.

```
public class Example {
    public void print(Set<String> strSet) { }
    public void print(Set<Integer> intSet) { }
}
```

The overloads would all share the same classfile representation and will generate a compile-time error.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotOverload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Parameter-Type is being erased at runtime. So the signature is identical.

Check [one of the other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268277/erasure-of-method-is-the-same-as-another-method-in-type) here for details.